# Docker Compose on Mac - Image Location

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for local development on my Mac.  I have multiple images being built with docker compose.  My docker and docker-compose set up is very standard.  Now I want to share my locally built image file with someone.  Where are these local files stored?

Searching a bit gave me answers like:

`~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`

But then how can I extract one image from this and share?  I tried running the `tty` that is present with it, but to no avail.

Docker Version: 18.03 Docker for Mac

Docker compose Version: 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [docker-hub](https://hub.docker.com/) account (which is free), then you can use docker push command to save docker image into registry and use docker pull to pull on other machine.

Another solution is to use **save + import** commands.

For that you can use `docker save` and `docker import` commands.

```
docker@default:~$ docker save --help

Usage:  docker save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)

Options:
  -o, --output string   Write to a file, instead of STDOUT
docker@default:~$
```

After that you have TAR file on your file system (check -o value) then transfer the file to another machine and execute `docker import`

```
docker@default:~$ docker import --help

Usage:  docker import [OPTIONS] file|URL|- [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

Import the contents from a tarball to create a filesystem image

Options:
  -c, --change list      Apply Dockerfile instruction to the created image
  -m, --message string   Set commit message for imported image
docker@default:~$
```

Comment: I can do that, but before that I want the location of my existing image in local machine.

Comment: You really don't need to see where is the images in the host machine. docker know where to look for. If you still want to know execute following command ``docker info | grep -i 'Docker Root' `` and you will see the expanded file system.... but you can not transfer it to any other system and reuse it.

Comment: See docker save command is not asking location of the image - it is simply asking image name.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the solution with `docker-compose` is using the `docker save` command.  We do not need to know the locations of images as @fly2matrix mentioned.  We can use the `docker save` command to save the image in TAR file.

```
docker save --output image-name.tar image-name:tag
```

Then this image can be shared and loaded by other users through:

```
docker load --input image-name.tar
```